# python: Getting error when importing type requests.models.Response into dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, api, dataframe, python-requests

I'm new to python and I'm trying to use the census geocoding services API to geocode addresses then convert the output to a dataframe. I've been able to read in my address file and I can see the output, but I can't seem to figure out how to import it into a dataframe. I provided the code I used below as well as the contents of the address file.

The output does not appear to be in JSON format, but rather CSV. I tried to import the output as I would a CSV file, but I couldn't figure out how to import the variable as I would a CSV file and I couldn't figure out how to export the output to a CSV file that I could import.

The URL describing the API is https://geocoding.geo.census.gov/geocode...es_API.pdf

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json
url = 'https://geocoding.geo.census.gov/geocoder/geographies/addressbatch'
payload = {'benchmark':'Public_AR_Current','vintage':'Current_Current'}
files = {'addressFile': ('C:\PYTHON_CLASS\CSV\ADDRESS_SAMPLE.csv', open('C:\PYTHON_CLASS\CSV\ADDRESS_SAMPLE.csv', 'rb'), 'text/csv')}
response = requests.post(url, files=files, data = payload)
type(response)
print(response.text)
```

-I tried the code below (among many other versions) which is how I would normally import a CSV file, but it generates an error message "Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'requests.models.Response'>"

```
df = pd.read_csv(response)
```

The contents of the address file I used to generate the geocoding is:

id,address,city,state,zipcode
1,1600 Pennsylvania Avenue NW, Washington,DC,20500
2,4 S Market St,Boston,MA,02109
3,1200 Getty Center Drive,Los Angeles,CA,90049
4,1800 Congress Ave,Austin,TX,78701
5,One Caesars Palace Drive,Las Vegas,NV,89109
6,1060 West Addison,Chicago,IL,60613
7,One East 161st Street,Bronx,NY,10451
8,201 E Jefferson St,Phoenix,AZ,85004
9,600 N 1st Ave,Minneapolis,MN,55403
10,400 W Church St,Orlando,FL,32801

The output is shown below:

```
print(response.text)
```

"1","1600 Pennsylvania Avenue NW,  Washington, DC, 20500","Match","Non_Exact","1600 PENNSYLVANIA AVE NW, WASHINGTON, DC, 20006","-77.03535,38.898754","76225813","L","11","001","006202","1031"
"2","4 S Market St, Boston, MA, 02109","Match","Exact","4 S MARKET ST, BOSTON, MA, 02109","-71.05566,42.359936","85723841","R","25","025","030300","2017"
"3","1200 Getty Center Drive, Los Angeles, CA, 90049","Match","Exact","1200 GETTY CENTER DR, LOS ANGELES, CA, 90049","-118.47564,34.08857","142816014","L","06","037","262302","1005"
"4","1800 Congress Ave, Austin, TX, 78701","Match","Exact","1800 CONGRESS AVE, AUSTIN, TX, 78701","-97.73847,30.279745","63946318","L","48","453","000700","1007"
"5","One Caesars Palace Drive, Las Vegas, NV, 89109","No_Match"
"6","1060 West Addison, Chicago, IL, 60613","Match","Non_Exact","1060 W ADDISON ST, CHICAGO, IL, 60613","-87.65581,41.947227","111863716","R","17","031","061100","1014"
"7","One East 161st Street, Bronx, NY, 10451","No_Match"
"8","201 E Jefferson St, Phoenix, AZ, 85004","Match","Exact","201 E JEFFERSON ST, PHOENIX, AZ, 85004","-112.07113,33.44675","128300920","L","04","013","114100","1058"
"9","600 N 1st Ave, Minneapolis, MN, 55403","No_Match"
"id","address, city, state, zipcode","No_Match"
"10","400 W Church St, Orlando, FL, 32801","Match","Exact","400 W CHURCH ST, ORLANDO, FL, 32801","-81.38436,28.540176","94416807","L","12","095","010500","1002"

The output for `response.text` is:

'"1","1600 Pennsylvania Avenue NW,  Washington, DC, 20500","Match","Non_Exact","1600 PENNSYLVANIA AVE NW, WASHINGTON, DC, 20006","-77.03535,38.898754","76225813","L","11","001","006202","1031"\n"2","4 S Market St, Boston, MA, 02109","Match","Exact","4 S MARKET ST, BOSTON, MA, 02109","-71.05566,42.359936","85723841","R","25","025","030300","2017"\n"3","1200 Getty Center Drive, Los Angeles, CA, 90049","Match","Exact","1200 GETTY CENTER DR, LOS ANGELES, CA, 90049","-118.47564,34.08857","142816014","L","06","037","262302","1005"\n"4","1800 Congress Ave, Austin, TX, 78701","Match","Exact","1800 CONGRESS AVE, AUSTIN, TX, 78701","-97.73847,30.279745","63946318","L","48","453","000700","1007"\n"5","One Caesars Palace Drive, Las Vegas, NV, 89109","No_Match"\n"6","1060 West Addison, Chicago, IL, 60613","Match","Non_Exact","1060 W ADDISON ST, CHICAGO, IL, 60613","-87.65581,41.947227","111863716","R","17","031","061100","1014"\n"7","One East 161st Street, Bronx, NY, 10451","No_Match"\n"8","201 E Jefferson St, Phoenix, AZ, 85004","Match","Exact","201 E JEFFERSON ST, PHOENIX, AZ, 85004","-112.07113,33.44675","128300920","L","04","013","114100","1058"\n"9","600 N 1st Ave, Minneapolis, MN, 55403","No_Match"\n"id","address, city, state, zipcode","No_Match"\n"10","400 W Church St, Orlando, FL, 32801","Match","Exact","400 W CHURCH ST, ORLANDO, FL, 32801","-81.38436,28.540176","94416807","L","12","095","010500","1002"\n'

When I tried

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(response), sep=',', header=None, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
```

I got the error message

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-60-55e6c5ac54af> in <module>
----> 1 df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(response), sep=',', header=None, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not Response
```

When I tried

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(response.replace('" "', '"\n"')), sep=',', header=None, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
```

I got

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-61-a92a7ffcf170> in <module>
----> 1 df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(response.replace('" "', '"\n"')), sep=',', header=None, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `response.text` looks like the `s` string below, i.e., has newline characters separating the rows, you can try:

```py
>>> import csv
>>> import io
>>> import pandas as pd 
>>>
>>> # let's pretend s is response.text
>>> s = '''"1","1600 Pennsylvania Avenue NW, Washington, DC, 20500","Match","Non_Exact","1600 PENNSYLVANIA AVE NW, WASHINGTON, DC, 20006","-77.03535,38.898754","76225813","L","11","001","006202","1031"
... "2","4 S Market St, Boston, MA, 02109","Match","Exact","4 S MARKET ST, BOSTON, MA, 02109","-71.05566,42.359936","85723841","R","25","025","030300","2017"
... "3","1200 Getty Center Drive, Los Angeles, CA, 90049","Match","Exact","1200 GETTY CENTER DR, LOS ANGELES, CA, 90049","-118.47564,34.08857","142816014","L","06","037","262302","1005"
... "4","1800 Congress Ave, Austin, TX, 78701","Match","Exact","1800 CONGRESS AVE, AUSTIN, TX, 78701","-97.73847,30.279745","63946318","L","48","453","000700","1007"'''
>>>
>>> df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s), sep=',', header=None, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
>>> 
>>> with pd.option_context(
...       'display.width', None, 
...       'display.max_columns', None,
...       'display.max_colwidth', -1,
...       'display.colheader_justify', 'left'):
...     print(df)
... 
   0 1                                                   2      3          4                                                 \
0  1  1600 Pennsylvania Avenue NW, Washington, DC, 20500  Match  Non_Exact  1600 PENNSYLVANIA AVE NW, WASHINGTON, DC, 20006   
1  2  4 S Market St, Boston, MA, 02109                    Match  Exact      4 S MARKET ST, BOSTON, MA, 02109                  
2  3  1200 Getty Center Drive, Los Angeles, CA, 90049     Match  Exact      1200 GETTY CENTER DR, LOS ANGELES, CA, 90049      
3  4  1800 Congress Ave, Austin, TX, 78701                Match  Exact      1800 CONGRESS AVE, AUSTIN, TX, 78701              

  5                     6         7   8   9    10      11    
0  -77.03535,38.898754  76225813   L  11  1    6202    1031  
1  -71.05566,42.359936  85723841   R  25  25   30300   2017  
2  -118.47564,34.08857  142816014  L  6   37   262302  1005  
3  -97.73847,30.279745  63946318   L  48  453  700     1007
```

If `response.text` does not have newline characters separating the rows (but has spaces as you have in your description), you will need to replace `io.StringIO(s)` with `io.StringIO(s.replace('" "', '"\n"'))`.

Comment: I really appreciate your clear instructions.  I updated my original post to include the output for response.text as well as the error messages that resulted when I updated my code using your suggestions.  I think I'm close.  I just can't seem to get all the way there.

Comment: Have you checked with `response.text` (not `response`) as I mention above (that is `io.StringIO(response.text)` or `io.StringIO(response.text.replace('" "', '"\n"'))`)?

Comment: @SAS2PYTHON to be clear, your error messages suggest that you tried `io.StringIO(response)` and `io.StringIO(response.replace('" "', '"\n"')` instead of `io.StringIO(response.text)` and `io.StringIO(response.text.replace('" "', '"\n"')`

Comment: Yes.  I changed my variable name to S to avoid confusion with the response object.  my lined read 'df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s), sep=',', header=None, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)'  and 'df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s.replace('" "', '"\n"')), sep=',', header=None, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)' but both are resulting in the same errors noted above.  When I paste the s.text value into the S variable using your code it imports perfectly, but your S variable is a text object but mine is a response object. If I can figure out how to convert it to a text object then I think it would work.

Comment: @SAS2PYTHON isn't `response.text` a string? if not, what does `type(response.text)` gives you?

Comment: Nevermind.  I see what you mean.  It worked!  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Nikolaos provided the answer.  My final code was

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import io
import csv
url = 'https://geocoding.geo.census.gov/geocoder/geographies/addressbatch'
payload = {'benchmark':'Public_AR_Current','vintage':'Current_Current'}
files = {'addressFile': ('C:\PYTHON_CLASS\CSV\ADDRESS_SAMPLE.csv', open('C:\PYTHON_CLASS\CSV\ADDRESS_SAMPLE.csv', 'rb'), 'text/csv')}
s = requests.post(url, files=files, data = payload)
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s.text), sep=',', header=None, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
with pd.option_context(
    'display.width', None, 
    'display.max_columns', None,
    'display.max_colwidth', -1,
    'display.colheader_justify', 'left'):
    print(df)
```

Thank you Nikolaos!